# Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: swift, optimization, grand-central-dispatch

I want to speed my code just a little bit. This is my code:

```
var loadedText : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "")
let changeThemeDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

    if self.selectedNote.content != nil
    {
        changeThemeDispatchGroup.enter()
        loadedText = self.selectedNote.content as! NSAttributedString
        changeThemeDispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    else
    {
        self.noteTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.noteTextView.attributedText = loadedText

    }

    changeThemeDispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    {
        self.changeLetterColor()
    }
}
```

I'm loading `loadedText` from database and I'm updating the text view. After updating the textview I'm changing the color of each letter. It works great. But now, I want to load `loadedText` from the database, change the text color and then update the text view. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the group and change the order

```
var loadedText = NSAttributedString(string: "")
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

    if let content = self.selectedNote.content as? NSAttributedString {
        loadedText = content 
    } else {
        self.noteTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.changeLetterColor()            
       self.noteTextView.attributedText = loadedText
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works.. I just need to change my function after that... Is it ok if I ask another question here? I tried to speed up my for loop using grad center dispatch, but at some point it crashes.. don't know why..

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: thanks, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956974/grand-center-dispatch-for-loop