# Grand Center Dispatch For Loop

Tags: swift, optimization, dispatch

```
for i in 0...attString.length-1
{
    attString.enumerateAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, in: NSMakeRange(i,1), options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (value, range, stop) -> Void in
        if let exValue = value as? UIColor
        {
            if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x2e4270))) ||
               self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xc0e1ff))) ||
               self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x7a99b8))) ||
               self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xaad5fb)))
            {
                aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)
                myValue = self.styles.blueHighlightColor()
                 //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
                //}
                self.saveChanges = true
            }
            else if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x385324))) ||
                self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xbde970))) ||
                self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x88a752)))
            {
                aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)
                myValue = self.styles.greenHighlightColor()
                 //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
               // }
                self.saveChanges = true
            }
            else if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x624b85))) ||
            self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xd6affb))) ||
            self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x997eb8))) ||
            self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xd6affb)))
            {
                aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)
                myValue = self.styles.pinkHighlightColor()
                // DispatchQueue.main.async {
                mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
                //}
                self.saveChanges = true
            }
            else if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x7b5b15))) ||
                self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xfbe769))) ||
                self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xb4a64d)))
            {
                aRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1)

                myValue = self.styles.yellowHighlightColor()
                // DispatchQueue.main.async {
                mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: aRange)
                //}
                self.saveChanges = true
            }
        }
    }
} // For loop end
```

I iterate through every NSAttributed char and I'm checking its background color. If it is clear ok, or any other color not defined in the if statements. It works fine, but it's kinda slow when I enter larger text. I tried using `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations:execute:)`, but it crashes, I don't why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for the outer `for` loop. Just enumerate the attributed string looking for `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`. Simply replace whatever range you are given with the new color.

```
attString.enumerateAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, in: NSMakeRange(0, attString.length), options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (value, range, stop) -> Void in
    if let exValue = value as? UIColor
    {
        if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x2e4270))) ||
           self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xc0e1ff))) ||
           self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x7a99b8))) ||
           self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xaad5fb)))
        {
            myValue = self.styles.blueHighlightColor()
             //DispatchQueue.main.async {
            mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: range)
            //}
            self.saveChanges = true
        }
        else if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x385324))) ||
            self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xbde970))) ||
            self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x88a752)))
        {
            myValue = self.styles.greenHighlightColor()
             //DispatchQueue.main.async {
            mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: range)
           // }
            self.saveChanges = true
        }
        else if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x624b85))) ||
        self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xd6affb))) ||
        self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x997eb8))) ||
        self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xd6affb)))
        {
            myValue = self.styles.pinkHighlightColor()
            // DispatchQueue.main.async {
            mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: range)
            //}
            self.saveChanges = true
        }
        else if self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0x7b5b15))) ||
            self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xfbe769))) ||
            self.compareColors(c1: exValue, c2: (UIColor(hex: 0xb4a64d)))
        {
            myValue = self.styles.yellowHighlightColor()
            // DispatchQueue.main.async {
            mutableAttString.addAttribute(attributeName, value: myValue, range: range)
            //}
            self.saveChanges = true
        }
    }
}
```

Once that is done you can improve this even further. Create a dictionary of color mappings. If `exValue` is found as a key, use its value as the replacement color.

Comment: thanks dude! It is very fast now. Can you show how to make that?